# How to get the values of multiple choose dropdown box

Tags: javascript, jquery

How i can get the value of this multiple choose dropdown box? I cant figure out how i can get the values. Please help on this. Thanks!

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
      <select data-placeholder="Begin typing a name to filter..." multiple class="chosen-select" name="test" id="test">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option>American Black Bear</option>
        <option>Asiatic Black Bear</option>
        <option>Brown Bear</option>
        <option>Giant Panda</option>
        <option>Sloth Bear</option>
        <option>Sun Bear</option>
        <option>Polar Bear</option>
        <option>Spectacled Bear</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" name="getvalue" id="getvalue">
      <input type="button" onclick="a()" value="Submit">
    <script>
    $(".chosen-select").chosen({
      no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
    });

    function a() {
      var value = document.getElementById('test').value;
      document.getElementById('getvalue').value = value;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: have you tried `$('#test').val()` ? It will return an array with all selected values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
      <select data-placeholder="Begin typing a name to filter..." multiple class="chosen-select" name="test" id="test">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option>American Black Bear</option>
        <option>Asiatic Black Bear</option>
        <option>Brown Bear</option>
        <option>Giant Panda</option>
        <option>Sloth Bear</option>
        <option>Sun Bear</option>
        <option>Polar Bear</option>
        <option>Spectacled Bear</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" name="getvalue" id="getvalue">
      <input type="button" onclick="a()" value="Submit">
    <script>
    $(".chosen-select").chosen({
      no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
    });

    function a() {
      var value = $('#test').val();
      $('#getvalue').val(value);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: How i can use this for filtering record from database? is that posible?

Answer (score 2):

[JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/7414/)

```js
    $(".chosen-select").chosen({
      no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
    });

    $("button").click(function() {
      a = $(".chosen-select").val();
      console.log(a);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://combinatronics.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://combinatronics.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <select data-placeholder="Begin typing a name to filter..." multiple class="chosen-select" name="test" id="test">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option>American Black Bear</option>
        <option>Asiatic Black Bear</option>
        <option>Brown Bear</option>
        <option>Giant Panda</option>
        <option>Sloth Bear</option>
        <option>Sun Bear</option>
        <option>Polar Bear</option>
        <option>Spectacled Bear</option>
      </select>
  <input type="text" name="getvalue" id="getvalue">
  <input type="button" onclick="a()" value="Submit">
  <button>
click me
</button>
```

Comment: How i can use this for filtering record from database? is that posible?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to assign a `onchange` event on the dropdown. And for better result use `.val()` of JQuery:

```js
$(".chosen-select").chosen({
  no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
});

function a() {
  var value = $('#test').val();
  document.getElementById('getvalue').value = value;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select data-placeholder="Begin typing a name to filter..." multiple class="chosen-select" name="test" id="test" onchange='a()'>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option>American Black Bear</option>
  <option>Asiatic Black Bear</option>
  <option>Brown Bear</option>
  <option>Giant Panda</option>
  <option>Sloth Bear</option>
  <option>Sun Bear</option>
  <option>Polar Bear</option>
  <option>Spectacled Bear</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="getvalue" id="getvalue">
<input type="button" onclick="a()" value="Submit">
```

Comment: How i can use this for filtering record from database? is that posible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this function with your HTML:

```js
function a() {
  var selectSelected = document.getElementById("getvalue");
  var collection = document.getElementById("test").selectedOptions;
  for (var i=0; i<collection.length; i++) {
    output += collection[i].label + ", ";
  }

  selectSelected.value = output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For dropdown options you probably want something like this:

'
var conceptName = $('#test').find(":selected").text();'