# ASP.NET dropdown to combobox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Part Number field displayed as drop down list in my ASP.NET webform.
User will select part number and System will store the respective ID from part table.

Since this is dropdown list, user is not able to type the part number. I want to use a combobox so that user can enter the initial few digits, and then suggestions will pop up like in a dropdown list. Also I want to show error is the entered value by user is not in the database.

I am currently using `asp-for` and `asp-items` tag helpers to show data in dropdown.

Is there a way I can get to display combobox instead of dropdown list?

Thanks!

Comment: In web you need to use any javascript or jquery library for this. [Example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_dropdown.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The Answer to above question can be found here:

Link: [How to get the values of multiple choose dropdown box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49568136/how-to-get-the-values-of-multiple-choose-dropdown-box)

Add the jquery Script from above link. for Select tag, use class as : multiple class="chosen-select" and finally add below script to show default value when input doesn't exist in database.

```
<script>
$(".chosen-select").chosen({
  no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
});


</script>
```